# How to solve EGLUT Error in ARM based Processor?

Tags: linux, arm

when I'm trying to clear the terminal using clear command .Im getting like this.

```
  root@iWave-G15M:~# which clear
  /usr/bin/clear
  root@iWave-G15M:~# clear
  EGLUT: failed to initialize native display
  root@iWave-G15M:~#
```

I have tried in X86 architecture it have worked fine. In ARM processor it is not working.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error when trying to use `clear` from within a custom bash shell script started by systemd. In my case the `tput clear` command accomplished the same thing with no EGLUT error.